# How to get max value of data by minute?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, google-bigquery

I m using this query

```
Select
    distinct
    creation_time,
    max(total_bytes_processed) as total,
    query
    FROM `project-id.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`
    where creation_time >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)AND job_type = "QUERY" 
    group by  creation_time, query
```

and i want to fetch the data of the last hour and get the max of the value based of the minute. For example lets say I have this sample data:

```
  10 ,2020-10-19 15:50:58.108000+00:00"
  20 ,2020-10-19 15:51:25.718000+00:00"
  45, 2020-10-19 15:51:55.356000+00:00"
  50, 2020-10-19 15:52:50.269000+00:00"
  5,  2020-10-19 15:50:40.527000+00:00"
  15, 2020-10-19 15:51:08.883000+00:00"
  25, 2020-10-19 15:51:39.082000+00:00"
  47, 2020-10-19 15:52:16.587000+00:00"
  60, 2020-10-19 15:53:02.901000+00:00"
```

How would I go about getting max value by minute for this this data?

my desired output would be :
since `10 ,2020-10-19 15:50:58.108000+00:00` is higher value than 5,  2020-10-19 15:50:40.527000+00:00 the maximum  value is outputted .

```
10, 2020-10-19 15:50 

45, 2020-10-19 15:51 

50 , 2020-10-19 15:52

60, 2020-10-19 15:53
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select max(value) value, timestamp_trunc(ts, minute) ts
from data
group by timestamp_trunc(ts, minute)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
with data AS (
  select 10 value, timestamp '2020-10-19 15:50:58.108000+00:00' ts union all
  select 20, '2020-10-19 15:51:25.718000+00:00' union all
  select 45, '2020-10-19 15:51:55.356000+00:00' union all
  select 50, '2020-10-19 15:52:50.269000+00:00' union all
  select 5, '2020-10-19 15:50:40.527000+00:00' union all
  select 15, '2020-10-19 15:51:08.883000+00:00' union all
  select 25, '2020-10-19 15:51:39.082000+00:00' union all
  select 47, '2020-10-19 15:52:16.587000+00:00' union all
  select 60, '2020-10-19 15:53:02.901000+00:00' 
)
select max(value) value, timestamp_trunc(ts, minute) ts
from data
group by timestamp_trunc(ts, minute)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Hello Yes I have tried this solution  it does work but out of curiosity  is there a way to include the  seconds as well?  . Lets say for the 51 minute of the the 15th hour  there are 4 timestamps   and since 45 is the max value of the  51 minute can I  ouput  `2020-10-19 15:51:55.356000+00:00` or would there have  be additional logic to be implemented

Comment: is it possible with this query to convert this into json response directly in bigquery?